# How can I access the content from a file in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am currently trying to build a specific app: 
I want to transform xml-files in a directory and have a `<div>` created for each of them.

this is my app.get (dirname is a var I set up, containing the path to the xml files)

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.render("test", { fs: fs, dirname: dirname, files: files});
});
```

for the route in question, while my test looks like the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <%  files.forEach(function (files) { %>
     <div>
        <%= files %>
    </div>
  <%  }); %>
</div>
```

So, at the moment I am generating a list of files, however, I want for every file to get its own div. These I want later to be grouped inside another div (that's the container, I have in my aforementioned code) instead of `<%= files %>`, what would I need to achieve this? ( I am setting up SaxonHEC together with saxon-node, as soon, as it is published in a current version on npm)

Comment: Is files, the array of filename that is to be retrieved?

Comment: yes. sorry, not the finest naming ...

Comment: Inside div, you need to do `fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirname,files)).toString()`

Comment: Doesn't using `fs` on the client-side cause severe security problems? (does it even work?)

Comment: It won't because it client-side will see the ejs rendered value of the file. Value will be preprocessed by ejs and only html will be accessible to client. You can also re-factor the code a bit.`app.get('/test', function(req, res){
var contents=[];
files.forEach(function (files) { 
 contents.push(fs.readFileSync(path.join(dirname,files)).toString());
});
res.render("test", { contents: contents});
}`
In EJS:`<div class="container">
  <%  contents.forEach(function (content) { %>
<div>
        <%- content%>
    </div>`